# The flows of electrons when the voltage is zero

Tags: electrons, electric-current, voltage, flow

As we understand, electrons can't be unmoving therefore electrons always moving or flowing. If the voltage is zero, where do the electrons move? Do they move everywhere?

Comment: What do air molecules do when the wind isn't blowing?

Comment: The air molecules are still moving around everywhere, so I guess same goes to electrons? I should've asked this on the chat though. So, zero volt reading on those instruments simply mean they can't detect electron motions that are too subtle?

Comment: With a sufficiently sensitive voltmeter, you can detect thermal fluctuations in voltage. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

Comment: So using a sufficiently sensitive voltmeter, these readings will be less than zero volts and will be in the negative numbers region?

Comment: Thermal fluctuations are sometimes positive, sometimes negative.

Comment: Not sure, Bob. My question is if the voltage is zero, does that means there is absolutely no flows of electrons. I think John Doty answered that question nicely

Comment: Also that means the ground in circuits actually have electrons flowing

Comment: Movement is not the same as flow.

Comment: Can you explain why?